# Mybatis <bind> tag cause SAXParseException

Tags: java, bind, saxparseexception

i'm using mybatis in my app. I'm using bind tag in my select element. This is my mapper code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
    <mapper namespace="myapp.model.MyDAO">
        <select id="mySelect" parameterType="myapp.model.MyParameterBean" resultType="hashmap">
        <bind name="SL" value="_parameter.getSelectList()" />
        <bind name="TNS" value="_parameter.getTableNameSuffix()" />
        SELECT NAME
        #{SL}
        FROM MYTABLE_#{TNS}
        </select>
    </mapper>
```

When i try to compile my app, i get a SAXParseException. Detailed error message is:

Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [C:\myapp\model\myMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "bind" must be declared.
Have you any idea about this bahaviour?

I'm using spring-mvc. For spring-mybatis integration I included mybatis-spring-1.1.0.jar.

Hi to all!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In this example I don't see any reason to use bind?

Comment: I know, i could use bind variable in this case. I need <bind> mechanism to insert entire custom sections in my select statement. For example i could need to modify select list or table_names or change completely where conditions.

Comment: I modified the example in a more explicative way... ;)

Comment: There are <sql> and <include> tags for that purpose

Comment: EXAMPLE CODE UPDATED!

Comment: I dont think bind was added until 3.2

Answer (score 0):

In my case is all completely dynamic.select list or table name suffix depends on parameters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="myapp.model.MyDAO">
<select id="mySelect" parameterType="myapp.model.MyParameterBean" resultType="hashmap">
    <bind name="SL" value="_parameter.getSelectList()" />
    <bind name="TNS" value="_parameter.getTableNameSuffix()" />
    SELECT NAME
    #{SL}
    FROM MYTABLE_#{TNS}
</select>
</mapper>
```

Answer (score -1):

Example of `<sql>` and `<include>` tags

```
<sql id="columns">
   SURNAME,ADDRESS
</sql>

<select id="mySelect" resultType="hashmap">
    SELECT NAME,
    <include refid="columns">
    FROM MYTABLE
</select>
```